# Cannot reach an aurora cluster in public subnets from laptop

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, terraform, amazon-aurora

I've set up the following terraform to provision an rds cluster, but I'm unable to connect to it from my laptop. The cluster is up because my other resources within the VPC are able to connect just fine. The instances are also set to have public addresses.

When attempting to connect I get:

> psql: could not connect to server: Operation timed out

```
  module "vpc" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"

  name = "${var.environment}-${var.app_name}-vpc"

  cidr = "10.0.0.0/16"

  azs                 = ["us-west-2a", "us-west-2b", "us-west-2c"]
  private_subnets     = ["10.0.1.0/24", "10.0.2.0/24", "10.0.3.0/24"]
  public_subnets      = ["10.0.101.0/24", "10.0.102.0/24", "10.0.103.0/24"]
  elasticache_subnets = ["10.0.31.0/24", "10.0.32.0/24"]

  enable_dns_hostnames   = true
  enable_dns_support     = true
  enable_nat_gateway     = true
  single_nat_gateway     = false
  one_nat_gateway_per_az = false

  tags = {
    Environment = "${var.environment}"
    Flow        = "${var.app_name}"
  }
}

resource "aws_db_subnet_group" "default" {
  name       = "${var.environment}-${var.app_name}-db-subnet"
  subnet_ids = ["${module.vpc.public_subnets}"]

  tags {
    Name = "DB Subnet Group"
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "db" {
  name        = "vpc_db"
  description = "Allow incoming database connections."
  vpc_id      = "${module.vpc.vpc_id}"

  ingress { # RDS cluster
    from_port       = 5432        
    to_port         = 5432
    protocol        = "tcp"
    security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.ecs_tasks.id}"]
  }

  ingress { # Open traffic
    from_port   = 5432              
    to_port     = 5432
    protocol    = "tcp"
    security_groups = ["${module.vpc.default_security_group_id}"]
  }

  egress {
    protocol    = "-1"
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}

resource "aws_rds_cluster_instance" "cluster_instances" {
  count               = "2"
  identifier          = "${var.environment}-${var.app_name}-aurora-instance-${count.index}"
  cluster_identifier  = "${aws_rds_cluster.default.id}"
  instance_class      = "db.r4.large"
  engine              = "aurora-postgresql"
  publicly_accessible = true
}

resource "aws_rds_cluster" "default" {
  cluster_identifier           = "${var.environment}-${var.app_name}-aurora-cluster"
  availability_zones           = ["us-west-2a", "us-west-2b", "us-west-2c"]
  database_name                = "dbname"
  master_username              = "username"
  master_password              = "a password"
  engine                       = "aurora-postgresql"
  vpc_security_group_ids       = ["${aws_security_group.db.id}"]
  db_subnet_group_name         = "${aws_db_subnet_group.default.name}"
  skip_final_snapshot          = true
  preferred_maintenance_window = "Sun:03:00-Sun:06:00"
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a rule to your `db` security group to allow access from your home IP address or Internet?

Comment: Also do you have a route on your subnets that allows traffic from the internet? Also, allowing all internet traffic go your database is a terrible idea. You should strongly reconsider that if that's what you're doing.

Comment: Is there anything else you'd like as part of this post?

Answer (score 0):

Your security group does not appear to have a rule that allows inbound traffic from your home network or public internet. You can add a rule specifically for your IP (may change when you restart your router) or for the CIDR of your ISP, and this should just work. The easiest way to test if your connectivity settings are correct is to do something like this:

```
telnet <db-endpoint> <db-port>
```

On that note, I would highly recommend communicating over TLS if you choose to do this. RDS already supports this via self signed certificates. Even better would be to not open up your db to public AT ALL.